# PHP - exec awk or fread faster for reading a column on very large file

Tags: php

I have a file containing plot data. Each line has 4 coordinates in total the data file can exceed 1 GB. Let's say, I would like to get the third column in a data file, which method should consider good practice and much faster?

Using execute:

```
exec("awk '{ print $3 }' data", $output);
```

Using PHP script:

```
$data = file("data");
$points = array();
foreach($data as $line)
    $points[] = $line[2];
```

Moreover, since the server does not allow to read large file, I have to use fread to read the file in several parts. But fread is not smart enough and some work must be done to combine the last line in each part. Any suggestion or any better method to read a column on a file in php?

Comment: You can add microtime(true) before and behind to get the cost time. and you can see which is faster.

Comment: fseek maybe (don't know, as system calls have also a certain cost)

Comment: What kind of data file is this? Is it CSV? Also, how is `awk` smarter than `fread()`?

Comment: Each value separated by 1 or 2 spaces. For a line, will have 8 values. Using awk will be much convenience when reading a column of value. Seems that using awk will use less resource since using awk, I can read (~5,000,000 lines) but using php foreach, I can only read (~700,000 lines) when the memory limits to 128MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `/file` is a 3.1 GB big file:

```
root# time awk '{ print $3 }' /file >/dev/null

real   1m42.430s
user   1m0.241s
sys    0m2.198s
```

okay. ±1.7 minutes for awk. Let's test PHP (without field splitting, just third char):

```
root# time php -r '$fp = fopen("/file", "r"); while (($buf = fgets($fp)) !== false) echo $buf[2]; fclose($fp);' >/dev/null

real   4m17.322s
user   3m16.571s
sys    0m31.625s
```

±4.3 minutes for PHP! I don't want to imagine how long it would take if I'd use @Jack's code...

PHP is far slower than `awk`. On really big files, use awk (invoked by exec()). As you see here, PHP spends a lot of time in user space (three times more as awk).

Comment: Yes, and I check that php uses much more resources. However, I always have a concern that php exec is not a good practice or someone may say that it is an evil. Should I always use exec or just mimicking the behavior?

Comment: depends. If you want to distribute software on servers which aren't under your control (e.g. where these functions might be disabled etc.), you should mimic it in PHP. (or best: check if awk is present and you can use exec(), and if not mimic it in PHP). But when you can, choose the fastest. Things like eval(), exec() etc. are ___only___ evil if you pass invalidated user input to it.

Answer (score 0):

fgets is your friend - http://ie.php.net/fgets. You can read the file line by line without having to load the whole file into memory.